# Trouble writing to SQL

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have been writing in VB.Net for a couple months now and have used SQL commands in my code many times successfully but am having trouble writing to one particular table in my database. I believe the problem lies in that i have a numeric column that i am trying to write to (I came to this conclusion because it is the only one i don't use very often) and my code keeps coming up with an exception: Additional information: SqlCommand.Prepare method requires all variable length parameters to have an explicitly set non-zero Size. with the code:

```
    Dim cn As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim command As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

    Dim VL1 As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
    Dim VL2 As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
    Dim VL3 As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
    Dim VL4 As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter

    Dim commandText As String

    cn = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectStr)
    cn.Open()

    commandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[HourMeterLog]" _
                    + "([MachineName],[TotalHours],[HLRD],[DateTime])" _
                    + "VALUES (@VL1,@VL2,@VL3,@VL4)"

    command = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(commandText, cn)

    VL1 = command.Parameters.Add("@VL1", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 25)
    VL2 = command.Parameters.Add("@VL2", System.Data.SqlDbType.Float)
    VL3 = command.Parameters.Add("@VL3", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10)
    VL4 = command.Parameters.Add("@VL4", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime2, 0)

    command.Prepare()

    VL1.Value = "MachineName"
    VL2.Value = 0
    VL3.Value = 735562
    VL4.Value = Now()

    command.ExecuteNonQuery()

    cn.Close()
```

I know my code connects because I have at least 15 other queries that work using this format. I would prefer to not use float to write to the numeric field but i had it work the first time I launched this code (not once since then).

Comment: for those who wonder i have the connect string declared for the whole class since i only write to one server on this program. it is dimmed: Server=Server;uid=User;pwd=Password;database=Example

Comment: It's been a while since I've done much SQL, but I don't think you need to supply the lengths for the Int or DateTime2 parameters. Try taking the lengths out and see if it works?

Comment: First - I'd advice you to scope your connection etc in using statements. Second - try just doing AddWithValue (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for parameters and drop the prepare (at least for now to keep things simple). If the code example in the link works you know your connection work. Lastly add a try/catch so you easily can see an exception if it fails.

Comment: I tried the AddWithValue method and it resulted in the same error.

Comment: did you try without supplying the size in the `command.Parameters.Add()` commands?

Comment: just remove the prepare, you use it only once anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335(v=sql.110).aspx) the Max character Length of the `DateTime2` is 27. So I have set the Length of `DateTime2` to 27 and its working fine.

```
 VL4 = command.Parameters.Add("@VL4", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime2, 27)
```

And my working code is,

```
    Dim cn As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim command As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

    Dim VL1 As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
    Dim VL2 As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
    Dim VL3 As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
    Dim VL4 As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter

    Dim commandText As String

    cn = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString)
    cn.Open()

    commandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[HourMeterLog]" _
                    + "([MachineName],[TotalHours],[HLRD],[DateTime])" _
                    + "VALUES (@VL1,@VL2,@VL3,@VL4)"

    command = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(commandText, cn)

    VL1 = command.Parameters.Add("@VL1", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 25)
    VL2 = command.Parameters.Add("@VL2", System.Data.SqlDbType.Float)
    VL3 = command.Parameters.Add("@VL3", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10)
    VL4 = command.Parameters.Add("@VL4", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime2, 27)

    command.Prepare()

    VL1.Value = "MachineName"
    VL2.Value = 0
    VL3.Value = 735562
    VL4.Value = Now()

    command.ExecuteNonQuery()

    cn.Close()
```

Comment: i will try that and see if it writes to my table. Here's hoping it works because i prefer this format to write to SQL vs the AddWithValue method.

Comment: That worked for me too, thanks man you're my hero. I get to keep my format how i prefer it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I guess I wrote the AddWithValue method wrong when i tried that. I got the command to write with:

```
Dim cn As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
Dim command As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

Dim VL1 As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
Dim VL2 As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
Dim VL3 As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
Dim VL4 As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter

Dim commandText As String

cn = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectStr)
cn.Open()

commandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[HourMeterLog]" _
                + "([MachineName],[TotalHours],[HLRD],[DateTime])" _
                + "VALUES (@VL1,@VL2,@VL3,@VL4)"

command = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(commandText, cn)

VL1 = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VL1", "MachineName")
VL2 = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VL2", 0)
VL3 = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VL3", 735562)
VL4 = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VL4", Now())

'VL1 = command.Parameters.Add("@VL1", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 25)
'VL2 = command.Parameters.Add("@VL2", System.Data.SqlDbType.Float)
'VL3 = command.Parameters.Add("@VL3", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int)
'VL4 = command.Parameters.Add("@VL4", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime2)

'command.Prepare()

'VL1.Value = "MachineName"
'VL2.Value = 0
'VL3.Value = 735562
'VL4.Value = Now()

command.ExecuteNonQuery()

cn.Close()
```

I would really prefer to use the format i had used before but i am happy that i at least am writing now. Thanks for the help guys. If anyone has any ideas on how to improve my original format to make it write correctly let me know. and for those who wanted a little info on the table I am writing too the field the Float was writing to is a Numeric(18,1) field. Other than that column the others can be extrapolated from the code.

Answer (score -1):

For the error messge, without know anything about your table...

"SqlCommand.Prepare method requires all variable length parameters **to have an explicitly set non-zero Size**"

From MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40959t6x(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

```
'Declaration
Public Function Add ( _
parameterName As String, _
sqlDbType As SqlDbType, _
size As Integer _
) As SqlParameter
```

Maybe your problems comes from:

```
VL4 = command.Parameters.Add("@VL4", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime2, 0)
```

Change it to

```
VL4 = command.Parameters.Add("@VL4", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime2)
```

Comment: I used a try catch and to show the exception in a message box and the data it gave pointed me at the    VL2 = command.Parameters.Add("@VL2", System.Data.SqlDbType.Float)

Comment: Ops! In msdn example for the method without size parameter, size is assigned later. Nice to see your issue its solved. Greetings!

Comment: System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime2 does need a 'Size' value of 1 - my example below.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a short example what the 'Size' parameter of SqlParameter has an influence.

Sample table is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DateTimeTest](
    [CreatedAt] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [SizeValue] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Sample code in C# is

```
    string connectionString = "Data Source=.;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Sandbox";

using (SqlConnection connection = new(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    
    string commandText = @"
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[DateTimeTest]
                       ([CreatedAt]
                       ,[SizeValue])
                 VALUES
                       (@CreatedAt
                       ,@SizeValue);
            ";

    DateTime timestamp = DateTime.Now;

    for (int i = 1; i < 28; i++)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);

        SqlParameter createdAtParam = new SqlParameter("@CreatedAt", SqlDbType.DateTime2, i); // i = 0 will raise an exception on call to command.Prepare()
        command.Parameters.Add(createdAtParam);
        createdAtParam.Value = timestamp;

        SqlParameter sizeValueParam = new SqlParameter("@SizeValue", SqlDbType.Int);
        command.Parameters.Add(sizeValueParam);
        sizeValueParam.Value = i;

        command.Prepare();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

As you can see, the value of 'Size' has no influence on the precision of the inserted DateTime value.

[image]

```
SqlParameter createdAtParam = new SqlParameter("@CreatedAt", SqlDbType.DateTime2, 0);
```

or

```
SqlParameter createdAtParam = new SqlParameter("@CreatedAt", SqlDbType.DateTime2);
```

will raise an exception on call to

```
command.Prepare();
```

Comment: So .... with size=0 you get an error. That was the OP question.
 "SqlCommand.Prepare method requires all variable length parameters to have an explicitly set non-zero Size"
The problem wasn't the field precision. You are adding info, not solving the question.