# How to insert DateTime2

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

What is the appropriate way to insert a value into a column of type `DATETIME2(7)` into SQL Server using a `SqlCommand`?

Here is what I tried:

```
DateTime d = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).AddTicks(1111111);

using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT DtTest VALUES(@d)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", d);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

But when I check the database for the value, I get:

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00.1100000
```

Which is the value rounded to `DATETIME` precision.

What do I have to do to get the precise value including the last five digits?

Comment: Right, don't use `AddWithValue` - you're making the code guess the data type, why do that when you clearly know?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify the column type like this:

```
var sql_parameter = new SqlParameter("@d", SqlDbType.DateTime2);
sql_parameter.Value = d;
cmd.Parameters.Add(sql_parameter);
```

Or more succinctly:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add( "@d", SqlDbType.DateTime2 ).Value = d;
```

Comment: Obligitory link to "[Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)"

Comment: var sql_parameter = new SqlParameter("@d", SqlDbType.DateTime2);
needs at least a Size value of 1 like
var sql_parameter = new SqlParameter("@d", SqlDbType.DateTime2, 1);

See sample code at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29699253/trouble-writing-to-sql/69582807#69582807